# Using custom password encryption in WSO2 APIM/DSS service

Tags: c#, http, encryption, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

is there a way to use a custom password encryption, like a C# file, to encrypt http headers being passed to a WSO2 APIM/DSS service? Currently we have an in place API/DSS service which will be used in a mobile application. Since it will contain user information we need to have a login method which will use a custom password encryption where when passed to the service will authorize the user and access his/her personal information. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply security policies to the DSS service. check these links,

1. [Secure data services](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Secure+Data+Service+Sample)
2. [Security implementation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Security+Implementation)

Based on above you may customize your behavior.